# Connecting to MongoDB from Camel-K

Tags: mongodb, apache-camel, apache-camel-k

How do I connect to MongoDB with Camel-K (version 1.6.0) ?

I've tried setting the host name directly on the MongoDB Camel component URI:

```
...
.to("mongodb:mongoBean?database=[redacted]&collection=[redacted]&hosts=[redacted]&username=[redacted]&password=[redacted]&operation=getDbStats")
```

but it insists on calling `127.0.0.1:27017`:

```
com.mongodb.MongoTimeoutException: Timed out after 30000 ms while waiting to connect. Client view of cluster state is {type=UNKNOWN, servers=[{address=127.0.0.1:27017, type=UNKNOWN, state=CONNECTING, exception={com.mongodb.MongoSocketOpenException: Exception opening socket}, caused by {java.net.ConnectException: Connection refused (Connection refused)}}]
at com.mongodb.internal.connection.BaseCluster.getDescription(BaseCluster.java:177)
```

Probably I should be setting a class reference in a properties file, like so:

```
camel.beans.mongoBean = #class:...
```

but then I'm not sure what class that should be?  - and what other property names to set?

The full Camel-K integration Java file I'm deploying to the Kubernetes cluster (OpenShift CodeReady containers, with the command `kamel run MongoDBTest.java --dev`), looks like this:

```
// camel-k: language=java property=file:integration.properties 

import org.apache.camel.builder.RouteBuilder;

public class MongoDBTest extends RouteBuilder {
  @Override
  public void configure() throws Exception {

      from("timer:java?period=1000")
        .routeId("java")
        .to("mongodb:mongoBean?database=[redacted]&collection=[redacted]&operation=getDbStats&hosts=[redacted]&username=[redacted]&password=[redacted]")
        .to("log:info");

  }
}
```

and in the integration.properties file I have:

```
camel.beans.mongoBean = #class:com.mongodb.MongoClient
```

- should there be some other class reference?
- if not setting the host name on the MongoDB Camel component URI, what properties should come in there under `camel.beans.mongoBean`?

Comment: It should work as if you set the hosts option, then the connection bean should be ignored.
There is an integration test using the hosts option (https://github.com/apache/camel/blob/f9b067c8d0ef0d0fee3ab51dbe39eb6067264a9b/components/camel-mongodb/src/test/java/org/apache/camel/component/mongodb/integration/MongoDbCredentialsFromUriConnectionIT.java#L49-L51)

Can you provide a reproducer ?

Comment: @LucaBurgazzoli, I'e updated the question with a full example of the Camel-K integration I'm deploying to the cluster, along with the associated properties file.  Do you see what needs to be added / modified?

Comment: can you please remove the camel.beans.mongoBean from properties ?

Comment: @LucaBurgazzoli, I removed `camel.beans.mongoBean` from properties and it gives the same result:
Client view of cluster state is {type=UNKNOWN, servers=[{address=127.0.0.1:27017, type=UNKNOWN, state=CONNECTING, exception={com.mongodb.MongoSocketOpenException: Exception opening socket}, caused by {java.net.ConnectException: Connection refused (Connection refused)}}]

Comment: seems strange, mind opening an issue ?

Comment: Would be glad to.  Here?: https://github.com/apache/camel-k/issues

Comment: Opened an issue here:  https://github.com/apache/camel-k/issues/2684

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The solution was to set the [quarkus.mongodb...](https://quarkus.io/guides/mongodb#configuration-reference) [Camel Quarkus MongoDB](https://camel.apache.org/camel-quarkus/latest/reference/extensions/mongodb.html) properties, as pointed out here:  https://github.com/apache/camel-k/issues/2684#issuecomment-939798018